# Check a transaction by txHash and confirm if user transfered right amount

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, bitcoin-testnet

I am facing a problem when checking a transaction in the Rinkeby network.

**Overview**: I have a transaction hash (txHash), so I want to know if users transfer from their wallet to my wallet with a specific amount.

So I connect to rpc and have the provider, I got the full info of transaction by using getTransactionreceipt function, and use abi json to parse the data encoded,

**BUT**, some transaction have 1 logs, others has 2,3,4... logs, and the value amount of transaction is in logs of response, so what should I do now? check data at logs[0] or foreach the logs and find the right log

**For example,**

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd0296c60df12ccdcdb5fab3d61c4c05c22820d543a76bf741b4ee6f8565f3327
I get 0 logs , transaction success
[image: logs]

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x50df0b293537ab076b7738fe6205239bf1a3e39510667d5ffe20d4dbb7b0fc09
I get 1 logs , transaction success

[image]

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9305efb42f70d4289fcf39c6f8377855deeef512b12af654f31815a714722186#eventlog
I get 4 logs , transaction success but not show detail
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) --> "Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem."

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there are two possibilities for transactions not to show logs, one is that the recipient is not a contract, and the other is that the creator of the contract doesn't use event functions for the methods you call. :)